# Why is sleep() in the time-module and not in threading-module?

Tags: python

Why is the sleep method (for sleeping a thread for some time) stored in the time-module and not in the threading-module (like in java).

I mean, is it not much more related to thread?

Comment: It is possible to build Python without threading support... should that also imply `sleep()` is not available?

Comment: every script has at least one thread (main) i think.

Comment: Okay, if you want to split hairs then it is possible to build Python without *multithreading* support.

Comment: but since every python script has at least one thread, there wouldn't be a problem if sleep is stored in threading. Sorry, i'm a bit new to python. Just wanted to be sure, that i haven't missunderstood sleep in a critical way.

Comment: @GregHewgill It is possible to build multi-threading Python without needing `time`... should that imply no thread may `sleep`?

Comment: @gecco: I don't understand what you mean by "without needing `time`" - the `time` module is part of the Python standard library. All Python programs may call `time.sleep()`.

Comment: @GregHewgill ok I misunderstood your post. I though you mean _building_ a python app, not _building_ Python itself... you are right.

Answer (score 3):

Sleep method in `time` module is derived from *nix `sleep` function (in unistd.h). It's not more thread related, it's a general function for stopping the execution of the program (or script)

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep` pauses the execution of the program/script. As a thread can also be regarded as a second program that can interact with the main thread/program, it also affects threads. Regarding the fact that `sleep` pauses the thread/program/whatever for a certain *time*, it is surely not wrong to put it into the `time` module.

Comment: Please don't do this. That will just make your code harder to understand.